# Overflow hidden not working with jQuery .css click event

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm assigning `overflow: hidden` but it does not seem to work

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9s9vW/)

html

```
<ul class="list-container">
    <li>items items</li>
    <li>items items</li>
    <li>items items</li>
    <li>items items</li>
    <li>items items</li>
    <li>items items</li>
    <li>items items</li>
    <li>items items</li>
    <li>items items</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="hide_list">Hide list</a>
```

jQuery

```
$('.hide_list').click(function() {
        $('.list-container').animate({width: "2px"});
        $('.list-container').css("overflow","hidden");
    });
```

I an trying to achieve a slide shut effect on a div. Even if there was another way to do it, i'm not sure why this isn't working though.

Comment: you may need to specify a height?

Comment: @Tim This didn't work unfortunately

Comment: move the `overflow:hidden` setting in the css; or before the animation

Comment: Can we upvote this question to help other users. It took me a while to find the issue as i thought the problem was within my script else where, and then i thought the problem was in my css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to swap them.

```
$('.hide_list').click(function() {
    $('.list-container').css("overflow","hidden");
    $('.list-container').animate({width: "2px"});
});
```

Comment: Wow! this worked, how strange. I hope we can upvote this question to help other users. This caught me out for a while as I thought the error was somewhere else in my script causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think jquery removes overflow hidden if you set the height or width to something different to 0 while using animation. Using a callback for the animate method solves it:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/9s9vW/5/

```
$('.hide_list').click(function() {
    $('.list-container').animate({height: "2px"}, function() {
        $('.list-container').css("overflow","hidden");
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. But i'm just going to swap them around because that also works. +1

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you set the overflow with jquery, this could be done with css and then the overflow doesn't get removed. Also when using the code as it, the li elements get an extra line. This can be stopped by giving the li elements a width.

Comment: The reason I set overflow hidden is because when it animated to `2px` it was still showing, as if overflow was accepted as standard

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have to call overflow: hidden once the animation ends. During the animation jquery adds styles inline and they overwrite your .css("overflow", "hidden"). Here is how it should be written http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/9s9vW/6/

```
$('.hide_list').click(function() {
    $('.list-container').animate({width: "2px"}, function() {
        $('.list-container').css("overflow", "hidden");
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. But i'm just going to swap them around because that also works. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it like this:

```
        $("#div").stop(true,false).animate({
           width: '2px'
        },500);
```

Don't worry about the .stop(true,false) - all that is doing is ensuring the event doesn't keep running.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to hide the "list-container" with effect you should probably use this:

```
$('.hide_list').click(function() {
    $('.list-container').animate({height: "2px"});
    $('.list-container').hide(2000);
});
```

or without effect

```
$('.hide_list').click(function() {
    $('.list-container').animate({width: "2px"});
    $('.list-container').css("display","none");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your javascript. try this code:

```
$('.hide_list').click(function() {
    $('.list-container').animate({width: "2px"});
$('.list-container').css({"overflow":"hidden"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

swap the below code from

```
$('.list-container').animate({width: "10px"}); 

 $('.list-container').css("overflow","hidden");
```

to

```
 $('.list-container').css("overflow","hidden");
    $('.list-container').animate({width: "10px"});
```